# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error when running app

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

I have this code that is supposed to load the attributes of an XML file to a string variable when the user clicks a button:

```
    public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("C:/Structure.xml");
        Visit(doc.Root);


    }

    public static void Visit(XElement element)
    {

        string siteURL1 = element.Attribute("URL").Value;
        string siteTitle1 = element.Attribute("siteTitle").Value;
        string siteDescription1 = element.Attribute("siteDescription").Value;
        string siteTemplate = element.Attribute("siteTemplate").Value;
        string name = element.Attribute("type").Value;
        Execute(name, siteURL1, siteTitle1, siteDescription1, siteTemplate); 
}
```

But when I deploy the webpart, and click the button, I get the "NullreferenceException was unhandled by user code / Object reference not set to an instance of an object" errors. on:

```
  string siteURL1 = element.Attribute("URL").Value;"
```

Any idea of what I may be doing wrong?

This is what the structure looks something like this:

```
<root>
  <level1 name="level1A"
          type="Private"
          template="3 
          siteTitle="Private"
          siteDescription="Private Site"  
          URL"private">
    <level2 name="level2A">
      <level3 name="level3A">
        <level4 name="level4A">
          <level5 name="level5A">
            <level6 name="level6A">
              <level7 name="level7A">
                <level8 name="level8A"></level8>
              </level7>
            </level6>
          </level5>
        </level4>
      </level3>
    </level2>
  </level1>
</root>
```

Comment: Please show the contents of Structure.xml

Comment: Show a sample of your xml file to get better help.

Comment: I just added a sample of my XML. It's similar to this but with many more elements. Some elements have the URL attribute and some don't. Could this be causing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of two things I could see being wrong...

Either the `object` `element` is `null`

or

the `attribute` URL doesn't exist for that `element`

Try something like...

```
var url = element.Attribute("URL");
string siteURL1;

if(url != null)
{
   siteURL1 = url.Value;
}
```

Comment: Some elements have the URL attributes and some don't. Is this the root of the problem?

Comment: Yes, do a check to see if it's null, check my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

`element.Attribute("URL")` is null.  You will need to inspect your data (XML) to see why that is.  Your code assumes a certain structure that appears to be incorrect.  Look closely at the element being passed in.

Answer (score 0):

Make some validations to assure `doc` is not null after `XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("C:/Structure.xml");`. Do you have access to that XML file on that location after deploying?

Answer (score 0):

There are some other things that can be wrong, here a quick list:

1. your XML doesn't have an attribute XML.
2. your XML contains namespace information which you're not parsing
3. your XML root element is not the one you're expecting

Run debugging and look on the element you're passing into the Visit method.